# How do I access the form object of spring mvc in a jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form object with a form like :

```
<form:form commandName="search" id="xmsimplify-form" method="POST">
    <form:hidden path="typeOfSearch" />
    [...]
</form>
```

I would like to retrieved the value of the field `typeOfSearch` in the a scriplet in the header (before the actual tag form)

```
<%
    String typeOfSearch = [????] 

    if ("somevalue".equals(typeOfSearch) ) {
        [...]
    }
%>
```

What would be the best thing to put instead of the [????]?

If there a way to retrieve the form bean in the request attribute or that page attribue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended method would be do it JSTL style

```
<c:if test='${search.typeOfSearch == "somevalue"}'>
    [...]
</c:if>
```

But if you really want you can pull objects from the model map directly from the request.

```
final SomeForm form = (SomeForm) request.getAttribute("someForm");
if(form.getTypeOfSearch().equals("somevalue") {
}
```